# Click on a button you add after the page is loaded

Tags: jquery

I create the button through js and add it to the html when the user opens it adds a product to my order and adds a button to remove the same product, and it is in that button that I am giving the problem. The button has the class *deletePrato* but as it reads the .click () before creating the button it is not reacting as I want

```
$('#orderDiv').click(function() {
    $('#escondido').hide();
    $('#ordersDiv').show();
    for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
      if (order[i] == food[contador]['id']) {
        orderVerificacao = true;
        quantityTemp = $('#quantity'+order[i]).val();
        $('#quantity'+order[i]).val(++quantityTemp);
      }
    }
    if (!orderVerificacao) {
      order[contadorOrder] = food[contador]['id'];
      // This is here I add a new button
      $('#ordersDiv').append('<p class="deletePrato" value="'+food[contador]['id']+'">X</p>');
      console.log(order);
      contadorOrder++;
      // Here I call the function to read .click()
      deletar();
    }
    orderVerificacao = false;
  });
```

But then as I added the button after having .click () I created a function so that whenever it creates a new button it reads again .click (), I thought it would work like that but the button still doesn't react and without reading .click ().

```
// The function to read .click()
function deletar() {
    $('.deletePrato').click(function() {
      pratoDelete = $(this).val();
      for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
        if(order[i] == pratoDelete){
          var index = order.indexOf(i);
          if (index > -1) {
            order.splice(index, 1);
          }
          $('#quantity'+pratoDelete).remove();
          $('#escondido').show();
          $('#ordersDiv').hide();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I tried to change the *< p >* to *< button >* and create the attribute onClick = "delete ()" but the button continued without reacting. If anyone knows how to help me, I really appreciate it.

(Edit)
Here is my HTML, is a WebAR application

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./imagens/dimmersions_logo.png">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>AR Food</title>
    <script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/2.0.5/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/localforage.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts/lodash.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var resultado =<?php echo json_encode($resultado); ?>;</script>
    <script src="scripts/scriptIndex.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="mesaDiv">
      <p class="order">Table Number</p>
      <select class="formMesa" id="mesaId">
        <?php
          for ($i=1; $i <= $numMax; $i++) {
            echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <button type="button" class="myButton" id="start">Start</button>
    </div>
    <div class="deletePrato"></div>
    <div id="ordersDiv">
      <p class="close" id="closeOrders">X</p>
    </div>
    <div id="escondido" hidden="true">
      <div id="swiper"></div>
      <div id="orderDiv">
        <p class="order">Order</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tituloDiv">
        <p id="nameFood"></p>
      </div>
      <img id="loadingGif" alt="loadingGif" src="./imagens/load.gif">
      <div id="swipeDiv">
        <img id="swipeImg" alt="swipeImg" src="./imagens/swipe.png">
        <p id="swipe">Swipe for next dish</p>
      </div>
      <div id="ingredientesBar">
        <p id="seta">↑</p>
        <p id="ingredientesSwipe">Ingredients</p>
      </div>
      <div id="ingredientsDiv" hidden="true">
        <p class="close" id="closeIngredientes">X</p>
        <ul style="padding: 1em 3em" id="ulIngredientes">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="markerInicial">
      <img id="markerOpacidade" alt="markerOpacidade" src="./imagens/pattern-restaurant-menu.png">
      <p id="markerTitulo">Please point to the marker</p>
    </div>
    <a-scene arjs='trackingMethod: best; sourceWidth:1280; sourceHeight:960; debugUIEnabled:false' embedded vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
      <a-assets id="assets">
      </a-assets>
      <a-marker detect-marker id="marker" preset='custom' type='pattern' url='./markers/pattern-restaurant-menu.patt' smooth="true">
      </a-marker>
      <a-entity camera></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some message in the console?

Comment: @Mario No, nothing happens when clicking on the button no error no message on the console nothing

Comment: If you use the DevTools in your browser you can debug the javascript in realtime to see if the .click handler is being called. Also, your selector for the .click() handler is a class. Do you have any other elements with that class? Better to use a unique ID rather than a class for a single element handler.   Also, you reference the variable "order" in the handler function without declaring it - is this a global? What is its structure? if it not an array of the order values, your test  if(order[i] == pratoDelete) will not work.

Comment: Could you please add your HTML.

Comment: @Nikkorian 
I used DevTools and even when I click it it doesn't enter .click (), but in the Click EventListener my function appears but it is not executing it. The order variable is global and the if is working because I add the button there, just .click () is not working

Comment: @AlwaysHelping already added

Comment: @GonçaloPereira See the working solution below.

Comment: `orderVerificacao` could be false and prevent execute `deletar()` could you check if this condition happen `if (!orderVerificacao)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `event Delegation` so your `DOM` is listening to the click event for `dynamically appended element`. by using `.on`

Also to get the value of `p` you need to use `attr` to retrieve the value of clicked item.

I have added some comments to each line as well. Change your click function to this below and it should work fine.

Just FYI - You also do not need the function `deletar`. Its up-to to have it or not. `Event delegation` on click will call `.deletePrato` and will remove the that item you want to.

Run snippet below.

```js
//The function to read .click()
function deletar() {
  //Change your to click to this below.
  $(document).on('click', '.deletePrato', function() {
    //Get the p value like this
    var pratoDelete = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(pratoDelete)
  });
}

deletar()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="deletePrato" value="1">Click Me 1 </p>

<p class="deletePrato" value="2">Click Me 2</p>
```